# The third from a star: a riddle

Tags: riddle

> In a way the third from a star I am.
> I can dramatically change things
> for better or for worse.
> If spun I am then ineffectual I will be.
>
> Higher then me my friend is,
> clarify he did in the olden times.
> But if we stand together,
> closer to ground he will be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are

> "-" (minus/dash)

Because

In a way the third from a star I am.

> On the keyboard, "-" is three keys from "*"

I can dramatically change things for better or for worse.

> A minus sign makes a positive a negative, or a negative a positive

If spun I am then ineffectual I will be.

> Rotated by 90 degrees (to a vertical bar) and the meaning totally changes.

Higher then me my friend is,

> "_" (underscore) is in the upper position on the key

clarify he did in the olden times.

> On old typewriters, underscore was used to underline

But if we stand together, closer to ground he will be.

> "_-"

Comment: You are correct -_^*

Comment: Explanation for 4th line: some (most?) people write 1 as a vertical bar, and we know that multiplication/exponentiation by 1 changes nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> the letter N

Explanation

In a way the third from a star I am.

> Sun is a star and N is the third letter in sun. N represents negative

I can dramatically change things for better or for worse.

> Maybe a reference to N (Negative) in medical reports. Sometimes it refers to absence of some disease (Better) and sometimes absence of some required hormones or something (Worse)

If spun I am then ineffectual I will be.

> If N is spun in multiple of 180 degrees, it will be the same.

Higher then me my friend is,

> Referring to the next letter M

clarify he did in the olden times.

> In chats and conversations, 'M..' refers to approval (sometimes to something one did in past)

But if we stand together, closer to ground he will be.

> NM represents New Mexico, and is known for the variety of its landscape.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a reason for most of the clues but.... are you

> Earth?

In a way the third from a star I am.

> The earth is the 3rd planet from the sun(star).

I can dramatically change things for better or for worse.

> 

If spun I am then ineffectual I will be.

> 

Higher then me my friend is, clarify he did in the olden times.

> In olden times it was said that other planets(friends) where up in the sky above us.

But if we stand together, closer to ground he will be.

> Earth => ground

Comment: But the earth is the ground, so it can't get closer to the ground

Answer (score 0):

are you:

> The moon

In a way the third from a star I am.

> The moon circles around the earth, which is the third planet from the sun. so in a way the moon is the third from the sun

I can dramatically change things
 for better or for worse.

> tides, which also can lead to very high waves with floading.

If spun I am then ineffectual I will be.

> 

Higher then me my friend is,

> seen from the point of the earth the moon is higher up

clarify he did in the olden times.

> the moon was a little bit farther from earth long ago

But if we stand together,
 closer to ground he will be.

> if the earth and moon are close together, then the moon is closer to the ground (i.e. earth) we stand on.